# How to deal with both GraphQL Queries and REST API Calls in a React Application?

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, apollo-client, tanstackreact-query

BE application on our project is very bad. It contains both RESTAPIs and GraphQL queries, so I want to ask is it good to have both react-query and apollo-client on the FE app?

Or if not, can I install just apollo-client and use it for REST APIs like for GraphQL queries?
Or vice versa, can I use react-query for GraphQL queries like for REST APIs?

What are your recommendations and do you have same good setup and examples for the some of this 2 cases?

I tried to find the best solution on documentation pages, and on some articles but I couldn't find something that looks good. Chat gpt also doesn't help me so much...

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This question might attract opinionated answers, like this one:

1. It would be cleaner if your back-end and front-end communicated exclusively using GraphQL. Making both styles of requests from your front-end is just messy.
2. Your back end can use other services including REST-based ones, that is a very common pattern.
3. Apollo-client doesn't know how to make REST calls.
4. react-query can tie to both REST and GraphQL APIs but that's messy. You'd lose out on many of the features of Apollo-client including caching and state management.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I know it is really messy to have both styles of requests on BE and then on FE also but current BE is done on that way... 
What do you think for using both react-query (for rest) and apollo-client (for graphql) on FE?

Comment: Still messy but fine.